# How to eliminate \\n symbol in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

My code is

```
myvar = pulldesctxt()
mystr = str(myvar)
m = re.findall('(?<=uCI:).*?(?=ver:)',mystr)
```

pulldesctxt) returns txt and has

```
txt = mycur.fetchall() #which pull column data from db
```

and output is something like

```
[' A/HM/UC1\\n', ' A/HM/UC2\\n', ' A/HM/UC3\\n']
```

But don't want space before 'A' and want to remove "\n".
How can I eliminate those?

And is there any way to get string between uCI and new line/enter i.e '\n' `m = re.findall('(?<=uCI:).*?(?=\n)',mystr)` something like this?

Comment: Please update your question with `mystr`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
y = [x.replace("\\n","").strip() for x in re.findall('(?<=uCI:).*?(?=ver:)',mystr)]
```